# My first child theme wordpress - color issue

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi there I've been fiddling with a problem and am hoping for a straight forward answer before I invest a lot of time in customising this theme.

I'm using an EDIN Wordpress theme and I need to change the color and feel of the website. Basically - I want to replace all the #xxxxx color with my own #xxxxx color.

Normally I would grab the Edin theme - CTRL+F the color, and replace it with my own.

However, I learned It's better to create a child theme, and customise from there. The problem is, now i can't CTRL+F the color and replace it with my own and I am using chromes developer tool to figure out where all the colours are located. So I've done a couple, no problem. But it looks like I need to do it for every media query the theme is coded for.

What I'm actually looking for is:

turn all #xxxxx into #xxxxx

Does this exist? If not, whats the best way to go about changing the main color of the theme - which is blue, and found all over the website.

After making a child theme - the CSS stylesheet is completely empty. This is making it difficult for me to find all the parts of the website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nathan the best thing would be to copy over the stylesheet from the parent theme into your child theme and then make all your changes to that. Your child theme stylesheet will then be used instead of the one in the parent theme. WordPress looks at the child theme first for files, then the parent theme.

If you have the time you could then go and find all your changes and copy them out one by one into a new stylesheet and then use that instead like an override.

The thing to keep in mind is if the parent theme updates... if so then if you are overiding the stylesheet and they make any updates, your child theme will not get those updates. In that case it is worth the time to make the new style sheet containing just your changes.

Comment: Great - I did this and it works fine. I'd like to add for future references that inside text-editor Sublime it's possible to select all the #xxxxx at once and replace them with whatever you want. So it took me like 3 seconds to complete the job.

Comment: Yes Sublime is awesome :) hopefully someone might have a more elegant way to strip out the changes - maybe a file dif tool or something - for you to create one file with just the changes. I am not a front end coder really so im not sure :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change everything manually. Unless there is an implemented option already in the admin panel to change colors etc, not all themes have this option.

The example you gave how to change all the colors at once, it is doable if you are using less. Then you can change same colors or parameters in one place and it will change it everywhere. I would have posted this in the comment section but I don't have enough rep yet.

This is just my opinion, maybe someone will do some research on your theme and will give you a better answer. Cheers

Comment: Thanks I haven't tried Less but am accustomed to Sass. I was hoping for a solution along these lines but I think the solution from Simon would be best suited for me.